# How to gracefully stop a Java ExecutorService’s troubled thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, executorservice

I am submitting callables to executorService (fixedThreadPool).

and storing the reference of the thread in callable object.

now the problem here is, in these threads, I am calling someone else's callback method(consider we have a jar with one interface and that interface's implementation is done by the targeted product), so basically I have no control on what other product is doing in that thread.
so sometimes what happens is due to some socket connection issues this thread gets stuck for an indefinite time and now, here is the issue I do not want to wait for that thread to end I want to kill that thread gracefully.

I tried with thread.interrupt() but it is only able to interrupt blocked, waiting and sleeping threads. The runnable or working thread can not be interrupted by this.
(Note: I am able to kill this thread forcefully using thread.stop() but as that is not recommended I do not want to do that, I am searching for a graceful solution)

now let us say it is ok that I am not able to kill this thread due to some limitations but the problem here is if I call future.cancel(true) on my future task I am not able to free this thread from my executor pool, basically I can not reuse that executor task anymore(here basically I have a static reference of executor service which has been reused in the loop), I have even tried using executorService.shutdown and shutdownNow nothing was able to free that thread from executor service.

so is there any way to kill this thread gracefully and free it from executor service.

Comment: If my product absolutely had to import and execute foreign .jar files, I would find a way to do it in a subordinate process. Once you forcibly stop or kill a thread, you must assume that the process to which it belongs is compromised.

Comment: *due to some socket connection issues this thread gets stuck for an indefinite time* Can you elaborate (be more specific)? Because if the socket connection issues are related to the socket and/or its streams, then you can close the streams and the socket (if that is an option at all), which in turn will throw an `IOException` on the product which should be by itself responsible to shutdown gracefully if such an exception is thrown.

Comment: @gthanop that statement meant that if suppose I have made callback to a product using our interface's implementation and in that callback on which I have no control they hav db update query, due to some reason that query is gotten into deadlock, now in this scenario the query will no be executed and too it will wait till socket timeout now if you take a thread dump of this process you will find that this is a runnable thread in java and that can not be interrupted using thread.interrupt. I do not have a control on that stream I just want to kill that thread or that connection remotely from jar

Comment: @SolomonSlow can you elaborate a bit what do you mean by subordinate process

Comment: @Adi, I mean, a completely separate Java program that exists for no other purpose except to run the foreign .jar and communicate with the main program. I've done that in C and C++, but I've never done it in Java. I think you would use the [`ProcessBuilder` API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-processbuilder-api) or the [`Process` API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-process-api). Don't know which is which, but I'm guessing that one probably is higher-level/easier to use, and the other probably gives you more power to control the sub-process.